# JavaFX - Getting the index when clicking something inside a 2d Array

Tags: arrays, events, javafx, onclick, imageview

I've built a 2d array of ImageViews, and I want to be able to print out the indices of the ImageView when I click it (and use that information to change the pictures).

I've got the following code right now, but I don't know how to get it to print the x and y values of its location in the 2d array.

```
ImageView[][] mainGrid = new ImageView[8][8];
```

...

```
for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        mainGrid[x][y] = new ImageView(image);
        mainGrid[x][y].setOnMouseClicked(createMouseHandler());
    }
}
```

...

```
private EventHandler<? super MouseEvent> createMouseHandler() {
    return event -> {
        System.out.println("Clicked");
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: How about `createMouseHandler(int x, int y)` ? If you more more than just print it out, define an object (`Cell`) that represents one array element and holds all the needed information: `ImageView` , `x` and `y`. Use an array of  `Cell` objects : `new Cell[8][8]`

Answer (score 0):

The most general solution to this problem is to use the [getProperties()](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getProperties()) method of the Node class. You can use that to store any user information in a node you like and then later retrieve that if you need it. In your case store the indices and then retrieve them in your mouse handler.